# Array.filter breaking safari print

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a print function that works in everything except safari. When the print button is clicked, an error is thrown:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Array.filter( document.getElementsByClassName('printArea_1'), function(elem){
        $(".printing_list").printElement( elem );
    })')
```

The thing that is breaking my safari code is an Array.filter, witch works in everything except safari:

```
Array.filter( document.getElementsByClassName('printArea_1'), function(elem){
    $(".printing_list").printElement( elem );
});
```

I have tried adding a chunk of code that is supposed to make this work with safari, but doesn't. Can anyone help me get this to work, or help me write something that can replace it with something that works in all browsers?

Here is my full print function

```
function print_list(item_names,number_of_items) {
    var theText="<ol>";
    for(var i=1; i<=number_of_items;i++){
        if($("#" + item_names + "_" + i).val()!=''){
        theText+="<li>"
        theText+=$("#" + item_names + "_" + i).val();   
        theText+="</li>";

        }

    }
    theText +="</ol>";
    $("#print_content_area").html(theText);
        Array.prototype.filter.call( document.getElementsByClassName('printArea_1'), function(elem){
            $(".printing_list").printElement( elem );
        });
}
```

Comment: Your function shouldn't (and doesn't) work in other browsers as well. You want `Array.prototype.filter.call(...)`, not `Array.filter(...)`.

Comment: thg435, you are badass! Thank you, that did it lol.

Comment: [Array generics](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods) are only available in FF, I don't know how that could've worked in any other browsers.

Comment: Or `[].filter.call` for a shorthand with a a little bit of memory temporarily wasted for the empty array.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure how that could possibly work in other browsers. `Array.filter` doesn’t exist; your polyfill creates *`Array.prototype.filter`*, which is the correct function. You can use `.call` to adapt it to an array-like object:

```
Array.prototype.filter.call( document.getElementsByClassName('printArea_1'), function(elem){
    $(".printing_list").printElement( elem );
});
```

But `filter` isn’t the right function to do that; `forEach` is.

And… do you have jQuery?

```
$('.printArea_1').each(function() {
    $('.printing_list').printElement(this);
});
```

It seems like you should cache `$('.printing_list')`, too.

---

So you want to do this?

```
$('.printing_list').append($('.printArea_1')).printElement();
```

Comment: This is working, but it also opens the print dialog box 5 times, and then crashes safari after printing.

Comment: @user2089255: What is your loop supposed to do?

Comment: I added the whole function to the description, it is filling text from a list to be printed.

Comment: @user2089255: So why did you introduce the loop? Are you trying to print all `.printing_list` elements at once? Or all `.printArea_1` elements at once?

Comment: I am trying to get all printArea items and place them in the printing_list to print, only one print must occur.

Comment: Yea that breaks everything lol. This code is made by another guy, I don't know what he was doing here. I will pass this question to my boss, he will know what the hell is wrong here. I don't even know how to ask what to do next.